# Question regarding Tab bar controller

Tags: objective-c

I am using [self.view addSubView:tabBarController.view];

But because of this viewDidAppear and viewWillAppear is not getting called so if I want to reset my view or update the contents of it, its not happening. Can u help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HI After some googling I have found the solution for the question. If you are using tabbar controller....then u can use :-

```
(void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

method for invoking any function from other viewControllers.

Just you have to give

```
[viewController functionname];
```

that's it. Hope this post might help someone.

Answer (score 0):

If you're linking against iOS 4.x SDK and lower, you should avoid using nested `UIViewControllers`.

But if it is really necessary, you should manually call `viewWillAppear:` (and all others) and make sure `parentViewController` property of your child view controller is referenced to `UIViewController` subclass that owns it.

P.S. If you'd like to add `UITabBarController` to fill all window contents, you can present it as modal view controller over another view controller or use `rootViewController` property of `UIWindow` class

Comment: Thanks Andriy for response. Here is my case. I have a Login Screen. So for that I have LoginViewController.h and LoginController.m. When a user enter proper username and password, I am adding TabbarControllers to load 5 tabs. Everything loads perfectly first time. Now when I click tabs I want to refresh some contents of it. I have tried to putting NSLog in every function, nothing is getting called. I am stuck like anything.